# npm ERR! Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 while parsing near '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLI

Tags: reactjs, npm

I am trying to create a react app using following command

```
>npx create-react-app my-react-app
```

This ends in following error........

```
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

npm ERR! Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 while parsing near '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLI...'
```

I tried force clearing the cache after referring to one of the threads in other forum but it did not work for me, I also tried uninstalling npm but did not work.

Is there any other way I can fix it as now I have ran out of options ?

Thanks